# HP 1910 disable layer 3 mode

Tags: routing, switch, layer2, layer3, hp

Is there a way i can make HP 1910 works in layer 2 mode.
I check the web interface but not seeing anything
Also i enable the cli and went to system view but not seeing any thing related no ip routing or way to make the ports works in layer 2 mode ... my current setting requires layer 2 switch 
Please help

Comment: Switches do switching (layer 2 mode) out of the box.  Layer 3 features take additional configurations.

Comment: Indeed. 1910 is a L3 "light" device, it's only capable of static routing with 32 routes. If you don't configure VLANs, the traffic is switched. 1910 is a L3 "light" device, it's only capable of static routing with 32 routes. If you don't configure VLANs, the traffic is switched. I don't know whether it will route between directly connected VLANs out-of-the-box. However routing to a subnet requires an IP interface in that subnet, so if you create VLANs but only configure an IP address on your mgmt VLAN, no routing should happen.

Comment: Hi Ryan n Arimo thank you for replying....
@Arimo i tried that but the problem is that the switch by default is acting as a Layer 3 switch and when i create a mgmgt VLAN say 192.168.1.254 by default the switch create a default route saying 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 192.168.1.254 interface mgmtVLAN. So, traffic are all getting routing to the mgmtVLAN... If there is a way to disable ip routing ....

Comment: The switch should use default route only if it doesn't know where to send the traffic. If you have a client on VLAN 2 which has DGW in VLAN 2 AND the switch knows where this router is to be found in L2, all traffic from this client should be sent on L2 towards the client's DGW, nothing should bleed on your management VLAN. So if traffic of client VLAN is bleeding into mgmt VLAN, it suggests that either the DGW setting on the clients is wrong, or the switch doesn't know how to reach the client's DGW on Layer 2.

Comment: Thats what i though so too ... finally contact HP and they suggest to upgrade firmware and if its still not working they will provide a replacement ... will update how it goes ... thank you so much guys for replying .... Advance Happy new year to you all :-)

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

Like Ryan said, it's a layer-2 device *first*. If you don't configure any layer-3 features, it won't have any. Out of the box, it has no ip interfaces (maybe a default management address, not sure with the 1910) and all ports are in the default vlan (1).

The automatic default gateway can be removed, or replaced. But it has zero effect on switching of traffic. It will only *route* traffic sent directly to it -- i.e. if 192.168.1.254 (it's mgmt address) is the gateway on the hosts in your LAN.

Answer (score -1):

Got the replacment today and it was my switch all along ... the new one with the same config (Layer 2) works awesomely .... thank you all for all your help...